# Over 12V output on a 5V power supply?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led-strip

I recently bought two 40A, 5V power supplies (Letour) for 990 WS2812B LEDs. Each LED strip (3.3 of them total) is rated for 5V, 20A each. However, when I tested the voltage of both power supplies they were just over 12V.

Is there something wrong in how I am measuring this? It seemed to have worked for the vast majority of people on Amazon and there was no option to purchase a 12V version, so I'm assuming this is a 5V supply.

I definitely don't want to risk blowing my LEDs, and I feel like a step down board would be overkill. Better to return it and err on the side of caution?

Apologies if this is a no-brainer and the company sent me the wrong type somehow, but that would be really inconvenient if it is the case.

This is the link to the supply: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01HJBEKO4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I have also attached a photo of the data sheet.

[image]

[image]  [image]

Comment: lakerice - Hi, Please link to the manufacturer's datasheet for these power supplies. You mention Amazon - an Amazon seller's page doesn't count as a proper datasheet, but please link their page too. Can you also please add a photo showing the model number markings on these PSUs. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I added more info. Does this help?

Comment: @lakerice Add a datasheet, please. An amazon link isn't enough.

Comment: lakerice - Thanks for the update. That Amazon page & PSU label *seem* to eliminate one possible explanation. A datasheet would allow us to be more definitive.

Comment: There is a possibility that it needs some kind of minimum load to maintain regulation. Do you have a resistor you could put on there across the output terminals to see if it helps? Or maybe a 12V lightbulb or something? I am not saying I find this likely. Just something to try to see if it makes a difference. Anything that can survive 12 V and draw a little bit of power from the supply.

Comment: Can we assume that you switched the 110/220 switch (if there is one on the side) to the appropriate voltage before applying power?

Comment: The reviews dont inspire confidence.

Comment: @Hearth I have added the data sheet that came in the box.

Comment: @SamGibson I have added the data sheet.

Comment: @mkeith I have a bunch of 10K resistors...would that work? Or could I try adding like 3 WS2812B LEDs to test? The thing I'm also worried about is excessive heat from overloading...even if it doesn't kill the LEDs outright.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It came switched to 110V. From what I know this is the most common setting for North American outlets.

Comment: Put a whole bunch of 10k's on there just for fun. Put them all in parallel. 12/10,000 is only 1.2 mA, and the dissipation is only 15 mW, so they won't get too hot or anything. It will be fine. But I fear Spehro is correct.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/96V-240V-Converter-Universal-Regulated-Switching/dp/B01HO76O0G

Comment: There are whole YouTube channels dedicated to analyzing the dangerous and poorly made generic power supplies you can buy online from various fly by night sellers. They're almost universally not worth the risk vs a slightly more expensive product from an established company. Especially for something like a 40A power supply that is a serious fire risk in the event of a fault.

Comment: Perfect storm: Supplied by Shamazon, made in China and no on-line data sheet. I bet there's no evidence of a QA system either.

Comment: Unfortunately, even the good Chinese supplies like MeanWell have counterfeits and imitators that use similar logos MingWei, MenWael and such like. If there is no official store, then authorized distribution is best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anyway this could be anything but a wrongly labeled power supply. It's supposed to have overvoltage protection which should have tripped in **any** case.

That does not bode well for the QC and the legitimacy of any safety approval markings it may or may not have. I see no marking with a file number that can be verified.

Comment: I agree. I'm sure that's what it is.

Answer (score 5):

Your multimeter indicates low battery. You can't trust the measurement, unless you have verified it measures correctly even with a low battery.

Comment: I bet 10 € this is the problem.

Comment: Tested it with a fresh battery...still registers 12.4V

Answer (score 3):

It may need a decent load on it to start regulating properly.  Given that it seems to be outputting 12V, then a 12V filament lamp would be ideal.  For example a 12V halogen lamp, or automotive lamp.

If the voltage then drops to 5V then it it only usable with an appropriate load applied.

Comment: I tested it with 150 WS2811 LEDs and it was fine. I tested again with the multimeter and it was still 12.4V. So I got a few lemons :p